# Inputing data using an Android device in a Maui program

Tags: android, visual-studio, maui

My VS Maui program successfully enters data in the Windows Machine mode, but loses focus when run on an actual Android device. Clicking on the entry field causes the screen to show a blank field. What property in the XAML field must be specified ?

Comment: Please read [ask] before posting